# How to put watermark using Bootstrap

Tags: watermark

I am a newbie to bootstrap world. Is there a way to put watermark using Bootstrap ? If there is please help me out with a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
  <head>
        <title>Watermark sample code</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
          <br>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  Watermark sample code
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">  
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        First Line
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Second Line
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Third Line
                    </div>
                  </div>  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You Can Put Watermark in Body Tag or use this code inside div.
Change Opacity As Per Your Requirement From Between 0 to 1

```css
  body {  
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
 background:url(https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;  
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
  <head>
        <title>Watermark sample code</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
      <div class="container">
          <br>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  Watermark sample code
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">  
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        First Line
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Second Line
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Third Line
                    </div>
                  </div>  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```